# Babel presets when deploying to azure

Tags: azure, babeljs

I added `babel-preset-es2015` to package.json and `"presets": ["es2015"]` to `.babelrc`. When I deploy to azure I get:

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot-client.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "D:\\home\\site\\repository"
```

The app works locally. How can I fix the azure deploy?